# Pressed the button "Submit" 1 time, and several went into the cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I get into the loop as many times as I pressed the button "tail_alertlog_button"?

A modal window opens on the button "tail_alertlog_button", I close it and so several times. Then I in this modal window click Submit, and it loops (#modal_NumberLinesAlertLog) as many times as I opened the window with the button "tail_alertlog_button".

```
   $('.tail_alertlog_button').click(function () {
        console.log('click tail_alertlog button');

        var issure_name = $(this).closest("tr")  
            .find(".issuer")
            .text();

           $('.modal-title').text(issure_name);

        $("#modal_NumberLinesAlertLog").on('click', '#submit', function () {
            console.log('click submit button');

            var NumberLinesAlertLog = document.getElementsByName("NumberLinesAlertLog")[0].value;

            $("#loading").show();

            console.log('show loading from modal_NumberLinesAlertLog');
            console.log(issure_name);
            console.log(NumberLinesAlertLog);
            console.log('before ajax');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                url: '/tail_alertlog',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    'dbname': issure_name,
                    'NumberLines': NumberLinesAlertLog
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success', data);
                    $("#loading").fadeOut(100);
                    $('#info_text').text(data);
                    $('#info_text').val("");
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error', arguments);
                }
            });
            console.log('after ajax');
        });
    });

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('#info_text').text("");
        console.log(this + 'clear modal');
    });
```

- (index):160 click tail_alertlog button
- (index):209 [object HTMLDivElement]clear modal
- (index):160 click tail_alertlog button
- (index):173 click submit button
- (index):179 show loading from modal_NumberLinesAlertLog
- (index):180 vm_4testing
- (index):181 1
- (index):182 before ajax
- (index):203 after ajax
- (index):173 click submit button
- (index):179 show loading from modal_NumberLinesAlertLog
- (index):180 vm_4testing
- (index):181 1
- (index):182 before ajax
- (index):203 after ajax
- (index):173 click submit button
- (index):179 show loading from modal_NumberLinesAlertLog
- (index):180 vm_4testing
- (index):181 1
- (index):182 before ajax
- (index):203 after ajax
- (index):209 [object HTMLDivElement]clear modal
- 3(index):193 success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the modal is never removed from the DOM.

You're adding another click handler

`$("#modal_NumberLinesAlertLog").on('click', '#submit', function () { ... }`

each time

`$('.tail_alertlog_button').click(function () { ... }`

triggers.